# How to set a "3rd level" keyboard option in Kubuntu 18.04 for the Compose key?

Tags: kubuntu, compose-key

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

I set the *Compose* key currently to the `Alt` key to the right of the spacebar but then I lose the normal functionality of that key.

I don't know what 3rd level means in the image below. If I did, I could perhaps use any of the 3rd level options instead and regain normal use of the `Alt` key.

[image: 3rd level options for setting the Compose key]

There are several answers but they're all for the GNOME desktop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KDE to have 3rd level enabled and to allow entering *Extra Typographic characters* you should open *Keyboard* — *Keyboard Hardware and Layout* (`kcmshell5 kcm_keyboard`) and then set the following options:

- in *Key to choose the 3rd level* choose *Right Alt* (as an example)

  [image: 3rd]
- in *Miscellaneous compatibility options* check *Enable extra typographic characters*

  [image: typo]

and as the result you will get 3rd level for your keyboard layout.